# Templating function with params with async library

Tags: javascript, callback, async.js

I am trying to write a wrapper so that I can remove the duplicate code spread among different files. I have couple of workers which takes list of params and callback. If some condition is true it calls some other service and call callback with the result otherwise call the call back with an empty array.

```
Worker1.js
~~~~~~~~~
export function get(shouldCall, param11, param12, callback) {
  if(shouldCall) {
    someService.get(param11, param12, callback);
  } else {
    callback(null, []);
  }
}

Worker2.js
~~~~~~~~
export function get(shouldCall, param21, callback) {
  if(shouldCall) {
   someOtherService.get(param21, callback);
  } else {
    callback(null, []);
  }
}
```

These workers are actually called from collector as follow. I am using `async` library.

```
collector.js
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    import async from 'async';

    function doSomething(callback) {
      async.auto({
        worker1Result: async.apply(worker1.get, true, 'abc', 'xyz'),
        worker2Result: async.apply(worker2.get, true, 'mno', 'uvw')
      }, (err, result) => {
        callback(err, result);
      })
    }
```

I hope to call this template from collector something like this:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
  const serviceOneCall = async.apply(someService.get, param11, param12);
  const serviceTwoCall = async.apply(someService.get, param11, param12);

  async.auto({
    worker1Result: async.apply(template.execute, true, serviceOneCall),
    worker2Result: async.apply(template.execute, true, serviceTwoCall)
  }, (err, result) => {
    callback(err, result);
  })
}
```

I tried template something like below. Problem is I am not seeing way to pass parameter(s) to service call. Any suggestion?

```
template.js
~~~~~~~~~~~
  export function execute(shouldCall, serviceToCall, callback) {
      if (shouldCall) {
          return serviceToCall();              
      }

      return [];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply extra parameters to `execute` function and then use destructuring syntax or `apply` method:

```js
function execute1(shouldCall, serviceToCall, callback, ...args) {
  if (shouldCall) {
    return serviceToCall(...args);              
  }

  return [];
}
  
function execute2(shouldCall, serviceToCall, callback) {
  if (shouldCall) {
    return serviceToCall.apply(undefined, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 3));              
  }

  return [];
}
  
execute1(true, console.log.bind(console), null, 1, 2, 3);
execute2(true, console.log.bind(console), null, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```